# Mapping URLs using mod_rewrite in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

I have seen all others questions of everyone on page but i have still done my problem.
I uses smarty for my template.

My structure is:

```
-controllers
  - public
    - home.php
    - about.php
  - admin
-views
  - templates
    - public
      - home.tpl
      - abount.tpl
```

So..my link to about page : site_url('public/about.tpl')
=> can not access when click on that link
=> i realized that i can access that page with link : http://localhost/mysite/index.php/public/about

I want to remove index.php.
In my .htaccess :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /application
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 1):

Unless you've specifically configured it otherwise, `.` can't be part of the URL until after the class and method.

I think you probably just need to change `site_url('public/about.tpl')` to `site_url('public/about')` (also noticed that the `.tlp` is not in your example on localhost)

Comment: ohh..sry...I missed..my link is : site_url('public/about') not site_url('public/about.tpl') :D